# SQL server 2016 standard edition linux installation

Tags: sql-server, linux, database, ubuntu, server

Good day,

I have a simple and noob question.. please help me to decide, is it possible to install MSSQLSERVER 2016 standard edition in linux(UBUNTU SERVER OS) ? and it will use to a production env.?

Ive already tested to install it by this links:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu

please help me any suggestion link and learning materials is a wonderful help

Regards

Thanks in advance

PS: sorry for bad english

Answer (score 0):

You can start [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup#system)

this is also good. [Installing and Managing SQL Server 2016 on Linux](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/considerations-for-sql-server-on-linux/)

Comment: checking on it sir :D

Comment: hi sir it point me to install 2017 version, we want to use 2016 standard, because we have exisiting license on it.. REGARDS